# Html - active tab is not changing

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am working on Admin dashboard at the moment, and i'm looking at the example in:
http://pixaza.com/40-free-login-and-contact-form-in-css-html/#

The CSS looks like that:

```
*, html, body, div, dl, dt, dd, ul, ol, li, h1, h2, h3, h4,

h5, h6, pre, form, label, fieldset, input, p, blockquote, th, td {

    margin: 0;

    padding: 0;

}



table {

    border-collapse: collapse;

    border-spacing: 0;

}



fieldset, img { border: 0; }



address, caption, cite, code, dfn, em, strong, th, var {

    font-style: normal;

    font-weight: normal;

}



caption, th { text-align: left; }



h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { font-weight: normal; }



q:before, q:after { content: ''; }



strong { font-weight: bold; }



em { font-style: italic; }



a img { border: none; } /* Gets rid of IE's blue borders */



a { text-decoration: none; }



body { font-size: 1em; /* Prevents an IE bug where em's scale out of proportion */ }











/* ---------- CLEARFIX ---------- */

/* For modern browsers */

.cf:before,

.cf:after {

    content: "";

    display: table;

}



.cf:after { clear:both; }



/* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */

.cf { zoom: 1; }











/* ---------- GENERAL ---------- */

.round {

    border-radius: 0.3125em; /* 5/16 */

    -moz-border-radius: 0.3125em; /* 5/16 */

    -webkit-border-radius: 0.3125em; /* 5/16 */

}



p {

    margin-bottom: 1.25em; /* 20/16 */

    color: #9498a1;

}



.fl { float: left; }

.fr { float: right; }

.cb { clear: both; }



.half-size-column {

    width: 48%;

}



div.stripe-separator {

    background: transparent url('separator-bg.png') repeat-x left center;

    height: 0.562em; /* 9/16 */

    display: block;

    margin: 1.25em 0; /* 20/16 */

}



h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { margin-bottom: 0.625em; /* 10/16 */ }



/*Temporary styles*/

ul.temporary-button-showcase {

    list-style-type: none;

}



    ul.temporary-button-showcase li {

        width: 24%;

        float: left;

        margin-bottom: 1em;

    }



code {

    display: inline-block;

    background-color: #f8f9fa;

    border: 1px solid #eeefef;

    padding: 0.416em 0.833em; /* 5/12 10/12 */

    color: #2a2e36;

}



blockquote {

    display: block;

    font-style: italic;

    border-left: 2px solid #eeefef;

    padding-left: 0.833em; /* 10/12 */

    color: #9498a1;

}



cite {

    font-style: italic;

    font-weight: bold;

    display: block;

    padding-left: 0.833em; /* 10/12 */

    margin-top: 0.833em; /* 10/12 */

    color: #9498a1;

}













/* ---------- TYPOGRAPHY ---------- */

body, form {

    font-family: "Droid Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

    line-height: 1.125em; /* 18/16 */

}



p, .button, form input, ul#nav li ul, ul#tabs, div.side-menu ul li a, table,

.information-box, .confirmation-box, .error-box, .warning-box, ol, .regular-ul,

.custom-ul, blockquote, cite { font-size: 0.75em; /* 12/16 */ }



div.content-module-heading span { font-size: 0.625em; /* 10/16 */ }



form p input[type="text"], form p input[type="password"], form p input[type="checkbox"], form p input[type="radio"] { font-size: 1em; /* 12/12. I did 12 because they're contained within a P tag, that has font size of 12px*/ }



h1 { font-size: 1.125em; /* 18/16 */ }

h2 { font-size: 0.875em; /* 14/16 */ }

h3 { font-size: 0.75em; /* 12/16 */ }

h4 { font-size: 0.685em; /* 11/16 */ }

h5 { font-size: 0.625em; /* 10/16 */ }


/* ---------- COLORS ---------- */

a { color: #2069b4; }

    a:hover { color: #2a2e36; }



p a, p a:hover { border-bottom: 1px dotted; }



.blue {

    background-color: #2069b4;

    color: white;

}

    .blue:hover {

        background-color: #5081b3;

        color: white;

    }











/* ---------- WIDTHS ---------- */

/* Form Inputs Style */

.default-width-input { width: 20.833em; /* Default Value. Equals 250px for the 12px font size */ }



.full-width-input { width: 95%; }



/* Textarea Style */

.full-width-textarea {

    width: 95%;

    height: 12.5em; /* 150/12 */

}



/* Page Container Style */

.page-full-width { padding: 0 1.875em; /* 30/16 */ }



.page-limited {

    width: 60em; /* 960/16 */

    margin: 0 auto;

}











/* ---------- BUTTONS ---------- */

.button {

    padding: 0.833em; /* 10/12 */



    display: inline-block;

    text-decoration: none;

    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}



.dark {

    background-color: #3f4551;

    color: white;

}

    .dark:hover {

        background-color: #5d6677;

        color: white;

    }



.text-upper { text-transform: uppercase; }



.small-button { padding: 0.312em 1em; /* 5/16 16/16 */ }



.image-left {

    background-position: 0.833em center; /* 10/12 */

    padding-left: 3em; /* 36/12 */

}



.image-right {

    background-position: right center;

    padding-right: 3em; /* 36/12 */

}



.ic-left-arrow { background-image: url("icons/ic_left.png"); }

.ic-right-arrow { background-image: url("icons/ic_right.png"); }

.ic-print { background-image: url("icons/ic_print.png"); }

.ic-cancel { background-image: url("icons/ic_cancel.png"); }

.ic-delete { background-image: url("icons/ic_delete.png"); }

.ic-add { background-image: url("icons/ic_add.png"); }

.ic-download { background-image: url("icons/ic_download.png"); }

.ic-edit { background-image: url("icons/ic_edit.png"); }

.ic-favorite { background-image: url("icons/ic_favorite.png"); }

.ic-lock { background-image: url("icons/ic_lock.png"); }

.ic-power { background-image: url("icons/ic_power.png"); }

.ic-refresh { background-image: url("icons/ic_refresh.png"); }

.ic-settings { background-image: url("icons/ic_settings.png"); }

.ic-upload { background-image: url("icons/ic_upload.png"); }

.ic-search { background-image: url("icons/ic_zoom.png"); }



.ic-table-edit { background-image: url("icons/table/actions-edit.png"); }

.ic-table-delete { background-image: url("icons/table/actions-delete.png"); }





/* ---------- MENU BUTTONS ---------- */

.menu-email { background-image: url("icons/menu/menu-email.png"); }

    .menu-email:hover { background-image: url("icons/menu/menu-email-over.png"); }

    .menu-email-special {

        background-image: url("icons/menu/menu-email-special.png");

        color: #7fcdff;

    }



.menu-settings { background-image: url("icons/menu/menu-settings.png"); }

    .menu-settings:hover { background-image: url("icons/menu/menu-settings-over.png"); }



.menu-logoff { background-image: url("icons/menu/menu-logoff.png"); }

    .menu-logoff:hover { background-image: url("icons/menu/menu-logoff-over.png"); }



.menu-user { background-image: url("icons/menu/menu-user.png"); }







/* ---------- FORMS ---------- */

form label {

    display: block;

    text-transform: uppercase;

    color: #2a2e36;

    margin: 0 0 0.3125em 0;

}



form label.alt-label { text-transform: none; }



form input[type="text"], input[type="password"], textarea {

    border: 1px solid #d9dbdd;

    padding: 1em 0.625em; /* 16/16 10/16 */

    outline: none;

}

    form input[type="text"]:hover, input[type="password"]:hover, textarea:hover,

    form input[type="text"]:focus, input[type="password"]:focus, textarea:focus {

        border: 1px solid #bbbdbe;

    }



form input[type="checkbox"], form input[type="radio"] { margin-right: 0.833em; /* 10/12 */ }



form input[type="submit"] {

    border: none;

    cursor: pointer;

    padding: 0.833em; /* 10/12 */



    background-position: right center;

    padding-right: 3em; /* 36/12 */

    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    font-weight: bold;

    text-transform: uppercase;

}



form#search-form input {

    border: none;

    /* The inner text overflows on the BG image, so we're setting a right padding to stop that */

    padding-right: 3em; /* 36/12 */

}

    form#search-form input:focus {

        /* Same as .dark:hover */

        background-color: #5d6677;

        color: white;

    }



form p em {

    margin-top: 0.833em; /* 10/12 */

    display: block;

}



form p.form-error, form p.form-error label { color: #cf4425; }



form p.form-error em {

    background: transparent url('icons/message-boxes/error.png') no-repeat left center;

    padding-left: 2em; /* 24/12 */

}



form input.error-input { border: 1px solid #ff876f; }

    form input.error-input:hover { border: 1px solid #b03e27; }



/* Styling the HTML5 placeholders */

/* So far they don't work in: IE, Opera 10 and below, Firefox 3.6 and below */

::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #858d9c; }

:-moz-placeholder { color: #858d9c; }











/* ---------- CONTENT BOXES ---------- */

.information-box, .confirmation-box, .error-box, .warning-box {

    padding: 0.833em 0.833em 0.833em 3em; /* 10/12 36/12 */

    margin-bottom: 0.833em; /* 20/12 */

}



.information-box {

    background: #e5f5f9 url('icons/message-boxes/information.png') no-repeat 0.833em center;

    border: 1px solid #cae0e5;

    color: #5a9bab;

}



.confirmation-box {

    background: #e7fae6 url('icons/message-boxes/confirmation.png') no-repeat 0.833em center;

    border: 1px solid #b7cbb6;

    color: #52964f;

}



.error-box {

    background: #fde8e4 url('icons/message-boxes/error.png') no-repeat 0.833em center;

    border: 1px solid #e6bbb3;

    color: #cf4425;

}



.warning-box {

    background: #fdf7e4 url('icons/message-boxes/warning.png') no-repeat 0.833em center;

    border: 1px solid #e5d9b2;

    color: #b28a0b;

}











/* ---------- MENU ---------- */

ul#nav {

    list-style-type: none;

}



    ul#nav > li {

        float: left;

        margin-right: 0.312em; /* 5/16 */

        position: relative;

    }

        ul#nav li:first-child { margin-left: 0; }

        ul#nav li:hover ul { left: 0; /* On hover, we make the submenu visible again */ }

        /* Persistent hover state, exactly the same style as the inner anchor on hover (.dark:hover) */

        ul#nav li:hover a {

            background-color: #5d6677;

            color: white;

        }

    ul#nav li.v-sep {

        border-right: 1px solid #3f4551;

        margin-right: 0.625em; /* 10/16 */

        padding-right: 0.625em; /* 10/16 */

    }



    ul#nav li ul {

        list-style-type: none;

        position: absolute;

        z-index: 999;

        margin-top: -2px;

        left: -9999px;

    }

        ul#nav li ul li a {

            color: white;

            padding: 0.833em 0 0.833em 3em;

            border-top: 1px solid #6a7282;

            background: #5d6677 url('menu-indicator.png') no-repeat right center;

            display: block;

            width: 100%;

            white-space: nowrap;

        }

            ul#nav li ul li:last-child a {

                border-bottom-right-radius: 0.3125em; /* 5/16 */

                border-bottom-left-radius: 0.3125em; /* 5/16 */

                -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 0.3125em; /* 5/16 */

                -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 0.3125em; /* 5/16 */

                -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0.3125em; /* 5/16 */

                -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0.3125em; /* 5/16 */

            }



            ul#nav li ul li a:hover { background-color: #7a8497; }


/* ---------- TOP + HEADER ---------- */

div#top-bar {

    background-color: #2a2e36;

    padding: 0.625em 0; /* 10/16 */

}



div#header { padding: 1.25em 0; /* 20/16 */ }



div#header-with-tabs { padding: 1.25em 0 0 0; /* 20/16 */ }



div#login-intro {

    background: transparent url('login-icon.png') no-repeat left center;

    padding: 0.312em 0 0.312em 3.125em;

}

    div#login-intro h1 { text-transform: uppercase; margin: 0.312em 0 0 0; }

    div#login-intro h5 { color: #9498a1; }



a#company-branding img { height: 39px; }

a#company-branding-small img { height: 30px; }


/* ---------- TABS ---------- */

ul#tabs { list-style-type: none; }



    ul#tabs li { float: left; }



        ul#tabs li a {

            border: 1px solid #eeefef;

            border-bottom: none;

            padding: 1.666em 0.833em; /* 20/12 10/12 */

            margin: 0 0.416em -1px 0;

            display: block;

            color: #9498a1;

        }

            ul#tabs li a:hover { color: #2a2e36; }



ul#tabs li a.dashboard-tab {

    background: transparent url('tab-dashboard.png') no-repeat 0.833em center /* 10/12 */;

    padding-left: 3em; /* 36/12 */

}


ul#tabs li a.active-tab, ul#tabs li a.active-tab:hover {

    background-color: #f8f9fa;

    font-weight: bold;

    color: #2a2e36;

}


/* ---------- TABLES ---------- */

table { width: 100%; margin-bottom: 1.25em; /* 20/16 */ }



    table th {

        background-color: #5d6677;

        color: white;

        text-transform: uppercase;

        padding: 1.25em 0 1.25em 1.25em; /* 15/12 */

        border-left: 1px solid #747c8a;

    }



    table tbody td {

        padding: 0.833em 0 0.833em 1.25em; /* 10/12 15/12 */

        border-left: 1px solid white;

        border-bottom: 1px solid #f8f9fa;

    }

    /* Alternate table row */

    table tbody tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color: #f8f9fa; }



    /* Push the first cell to the right so it doesn't stick to the table border */

    table td:first-child, table th:first-child {

        width: 4em /* 48/12 */;

        text-align: center;

        padding: 0;

        border: none;

        border-bottom: 1px solid #f8f9fa;

    }



    table td:last-child, table th:last-child {

        width: 7em; /* 84/12 */

        text-align: center;

        padding: 0;

    }

    table td.table-footer {

        text-align: left;

        vertical-align: middle;

        padding-top: 1.25em /* 15/12 */;

        border: none;

    }



a.table-actions-button {

    width: 1.25em;

    height: 1.25em;

    display: inline-block;

    background-position: center center;

}


/* ---------- LISTS ---------- */

ol li, .regular-ul li { margin-left: 1.25em; /* 20/16 */ }



ol, .regular-ul, .custom-ul { margin-bottom: 1.25em; /* 20/16 */ }



.custom-ul { list-style-type: none; }



    .custom-ul li {

        background: transparent url('menu-dark-indicator.png') no-repeat left center;

        padding-left: 1.25em /* 10/12 */;

    }


/* ---------- CONTENT ---------- */

div#content {

    background: #f8f9fa url('artwork-pattern.png') repeat-x left bottom;

    border: 1px solid #eeefef;

    padding: 1.875em 0; /* 30/16 */

}

form#login-form {

    width: 18.75em; /* 300/16 */

    margin: 0 auto;

}



div.side-menu {

    background: #3f4551;

    border: 1px solid #eeefef;

    width: 15%;

    margin-bottom: 1em; /* 16/16 */

}



    div.side-menu h3 {

        text-transform: uppercase;

        font-weight: bold;

        margin:  1.25em; /* 15/12 */

        color: white;

    }



    div.side-menu ul { list-style-type: none; }



        div.side-menu ul li a {

            padding: 0.833em 1.25em; /* 10/12 15/12 */

            border-top: 1px solid #f8f9fa;

            display: block;

            background: white url('menu-dark-indicator.png') no-repeat right center;

        }

            div.side-menu ul li a:hover {

                background-color: #f8f9fa;

            }



div.side-content { width: 83%; /* 100% - 15% for the side menu - 2% for the left margin */ }



div.content-module {

    background: white;

    margin-bottom: 1em; /* 16/16 */

    border: 1px solid #eeefef;

}



div.content-module-heading {

    background: #3f4551;

    cursor: pointer;

}



    div.content-module-heading h3 {

        text-transform: uppercase;

        color: white;

        font-weight: bold;

        margin: 1.25em; /* 15/12 */

    }



    div.content-module-heading span {

        color: #969dac;

        text-transform: uppercase;

        margin: 1.5em; /* 15/10 */

    }



div.content-module-main { padding: 1em; /* 16/16 */ }


/* ---------- FOOTER ---------- */

div#footer {

    text-align: center;

    padding: 1.875em 0; /* 30/16 */

}
```

The application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <!-- Stylesheets -->

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet'>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/application.css">



    <!-- Optimize for mobile devices -->

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>



  <!-- jQuery & JS files -->

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="/assets/script.js"></script>

  </head>



  <body>

    <!-- TOP BAR - Only if user has authenticated -->

  <% if current_user %>

  <div id="top-bar">



    <div class="page-full-width cf">



    <ul id="nav" class="fl">



      <li class="v-sep"><a href="#" class="round button dark menu-user image-left">Logged in as <strong><%= current_user.name %></strong></a>

      </li>

      <li><%= link_to "Sign Out", signed_out_path, :class => "round button dark menu-logoff image-left" %></li>



    </ul> <!-- end nav -->





      <form action="#" method="POST" id="search-form" class="fr">

        <fieldset>

          <input type="text" id="search-keyword" class="round button dark ic-search image-right" placeholder="Search..." />

          <input type="hidden" value="SUBMIT" />

        </fieldset>

      </form>



    </div> <!-- end full-width -->



  </div> <!-- end top-bar -->



  <!-- HEADER -->

  <div id="header-with-tabs">

    <div class="page-full-width cf">

      <ul id="tabs" class="fl">

        <li><a href="dashboard.html" class="dashboard-tab">Dashboard</a></li>

        <li><a href="../er_queues" >Full width page</a></li>

        <li><a href="page-other.html" class="active-tab">Other page elements</a></li>

      </ul> <!-- end tabs -->

    </div> <!-- end full-width -->

  </div> <!-- end header -->

  <% end %>



  <%= yield %>



  </body>
```

I am working with rails, and i only using the above css.
Now, i put all the tabs code at application.html.erb, and for some reason, the clicked tab is not highlighted, and the initial active tab is not changed (I'm looking at the source of the page, and i see the class="active-tab" is still on the old tab, although i am on another page.
Can any1 see the reason why ?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the class="active-tab" property on the other pages.
So in your current page, page-other.html you have :

```
<li><a href="dashboard.html" class="dashboard-tab">Dashboard</a></li>

<li><a href="../er_queues" >Full width page</a></li>

<li><a href="page-other.html" class="active-tab">Other page elements</a></li>
```

So in er_queues page:

```
<li><a href="dashboard.html" class="dashboard-tab">Dashboard</a></li>

<li><a href="../er_queues" class="active-tab">Full width page</a></li>

<li><a href="page-other.html">Other page elements</a></li>
```

In dashboard.html page:

```
<li><a href="dashboard.html" class="dashboard-tab" class="active-tab">Dashboard</a></li>

<li><a href="../er_queues" >Full width page</a></li>

<li><a href="page-other.html">Other page elements</a></li>
```

As you can notice the corresponding styles(class="active-tab") are set for the pages they correspond to in their respective pages.

Hope this solves your problem.